How to fix: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration?
This is the exception I got when I try to send message in my topic on confluent cloud
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new NetworkClient
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createNetworkClient(ClientUtils.java:252)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createNetworkClient(ClientUtils.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:523)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:462)
    ... 177 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.defaultContext(JaasContext.java:150)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.load(JaasContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.loadClientContext(JaasContext.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:167)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:119)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createNetworkClient(ClientUtils.java:223)
    ... 180 common frames omitted

The problem is that I think I've set up the security normally but I always get this exception when I send a message.
This is how I make my configuration to connect to confluent cloud
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${address-server}
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      
    properties:
      specific.avro.reader: true
      auto.register.schemas: false
      basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
      basic.auth.user.info: ${api-key}:${api-key-secret}
      schema:
        registry:
          url: ${address-schema-registry}
      sasl:
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='api-client-id' password='api-client-secret';
        mechanism: PLAIN
      security:
        protocol: SASL_SSL
      ssl:
        endpoint:
          identification:
            algorithm: https

all variables are correct. but when I try to send messag in the topic I got the error
In my configuration class I have these methods for handling my producer
  @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, SpecificRecordBase> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig());
    }

 @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, kafkaSecurityProtocol);
        configProps.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);
        return configProps;
    }

The KafkaTemplate
@Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, SpecificRecordBase> kafkaTemplate(CustomProducerListener<String, SpecificRecordBase> listener) {
        KafkaTemplate<String, SpecificRecordBase> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
        kafkaTemplate.setProducerListener(listener);
        return kafkaTemplate;
    }


Hi ! I changed the title to something more useful. Please make your title the error you're trying to fix in general. It makes others find your question more easily and also attract people who can help with that error. Have you searched the error text and tried out solutions yet?

Thanks for your comment. So, I've tried solutions but I still have the problem.

I'm asking because you are supposed to put in the question which solutions you have tried. I'm not just asking so you say "yes I have tried". I ask so you update the question and other people looking at the question can see what you have tried so far.

sasl.jaas.config should all be one line in the yaml... Same for schema registry and ssl config
